# How to set dataset's content to lowercase?

Tags: c#, css, dataset, dataview

Hi i have a dataset with all its content as uppercase,
This is then binded to a table on my webpage.

I would like to display the content on the table as capitalized but can't since its all uppercase already. With CSS i can only style it to lowercase and then not move it to capitalized.

So i need to move the content to lower case from my C# side so that my CSS can change the text to capitalized.

```
System.Data.DataSet ds = (System.Data.DataSet)Session["dsProspects"];
String strWhere = "";

System.Data.DataView dv = new System.Data.DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
dv.RowFilter = strWhere;

prospects.DataSource = dv;
prospects.DataBind();
```

If there are other suggestions on how to achieve this in a similar way that would be much appreciated.

---

Edit:
The big problem. You can't move text to capitalized from uppercase. This is why i want to have the data set in lower case so i can use: text-transform: capitalize in my CSS.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's upper case, you can have title case. You may loop through cells calling `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase()` or (because you're talking about CSS I assume you're presenting data in HTML) use `text-transform: capitalize`. BTW saving a `DataSet` in session may **seriously hit performance**.

Comment: you can use LINQ looping through tables and select the needed data where use ToLowerCase on the needed field or you can use Bind() on the View (if you're using WebForms) and do the trick there

Answer (score 0):

You can select your content in lower case with SQL. Use `LOWER` function in MS SQL (T-SQL).

Comment: I suppose the source data is fetched from database. If not than pure C# solution Tim Schmelter will do what is needed

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned the column-names or types, so i presume string-columns:

```
foreach(DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    foreach(DataColumn col in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
        row.SetField(col, row.Field<string>(col).ToLower());
```

you could also use [`TextInfo.ToTitleCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase(v=vs.110).aspx), then you don't need the CSS:

```
var textInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    foreach (DataColumn col in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
        row.SetField(col, textInfo.ToTitleCase(row.Field<string>(col)));
```

Comment: this is the error message i get when i try this:

'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'SetField' and no extension method 'SetField' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataRow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Pomster: what framework are you using? These are .NET 3.5 extension methods. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.field(v=vs.110).aspx So you have to add a reference to the `DataSetExtensions.dll`. But you don't need to use them. You can also use `row[col] = row[col].ToString().ToLower()`

Answer (score 0):

ply with `text-transform:lowercase` and `text-transform:capitalize`, when capitalize only the first letter will be in uppercase.

[CSS text-transform property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_text-transform)

EDIT:

Please check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/damithsw/kperLLf6/)

Comment: please see edit on why i can't do this. As mention i final goal is to have the text capitalized but its currently uppercase.

Comment: The first letter won't achieve what i am looking for, i also looked into that. say now i have A AND M PRODUCTS, its should read, A And M Products. Title case.